# Java sorting of an array and append it in another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to perform a linear search though a[] and append the result to b[]. 
Here is my code:

```
public class sorting {
    static int a[]={10,12,14,2,1,3};
    static int  b[]=new int[a.length];

public static void fn()
{
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j]){
                 b[i]=a[j];
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I am getting output as 333101. I expect {1,2,8,10,12,30}.

Even after finding 1 as minimum, loop continues and find 10>3 and replaces 1 with 3. How do I stop the loop when a minimum is found?

Comment: `int[] b = /* you try something first */ ;`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? As written, it is essentially a "write my code for me" question. Maybe it's a classroom assignment or something similar. Please edit to show what you've done so far.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any code of your solution you have so far, along with any problems you may be encountering, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Ok, so you've now edited your question, which is great. The issue is, you only edited to show your desired result (e.g. sort contents of `a`, and write sorted results to `b`). Good that you did this. But... you still haven't shown what *you* tried (or are attempting to try).

Comment: To EJoshuaS : for your kind information its not a homework problem.i got this question in my amazon interview.I was able to sort in a[] itself.but searching in a[] finding the minimum and storing in b i felt some difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `b[0]` if `a[0]` is the smallest value in `a`.

If you want to have a sorted Output in `b` you should probably to a compare including `b`in the `if` statement.

What would be the intended behaviour if some numbers are negative or multipe times in `a`?

One possible approach similar to your code would be

```
public static void fn() {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // initialize with large value
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            // search for Minimum bigger than last value already in b
            if (b[i] > a[j] && (i == 0 || a[j] > b[i - 1])) {
                b[i] = a[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this approach.

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    int a[] = { 10, 12, 14, 2, 1, 3 }, c;
    int b[] = new int[a.length];
    b = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < b.length; j++)
      {
        if (b[i] > b[j])
          {
            c = b[i];
            b[i] = b[j];
            b[j] = c;
          }
      }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
    {
        if (j == 0)
          {
            System.out.print ("{"+b[j]+",");
          }else if(j == b.length-1){
            System.out.print(b[j]+"}");
          }else{
            System.out.print(b[j]+",");
          }
    }
  }
}

output:{1,2,3,10,12,14}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).